# eclipse How to view variable (HashMap) with huge data?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have hash map with huge data. when I use eclipse debuger "watch" to view the keys, It prints many entries and then points.... which means to me there are also data which are not printed:
[image]

How can I view all data in my map?

Comment: expand the watcher tree (`>`symbol)

Comment: yes but this doesn't helps much with huge data, you can't easily find some certain data you are looking for :)